# Should you acquire a lock inside or outside an API method?

Tags: python, concurrency, thread-safety, locking

Let's say you have a class that you intend to share among multiple threads. Python example:

```
class ConcurrentClass:
    lock = threading.Lock()

    data1 = 1
    data2 = 2

    def modify_values(self, a, b):
        self.data1 = a
        self.data2 = b
```

Is it best to acquire the lock inside the method modify_values()?

```
# class method
def modify_values(self, a, b):
    with self.lock:
        self.data1 = a
        self.data2 = b


# calling code
co = ConcurrentClass()
co.modify_values(1, 2)
```

Or should you let whoever's calling the function handle that?

```
# class method
def modify_values(self, a, b):
    self.data1 = a
    self.data2 = b


# calling code
co = ConcurrentClass()
with co.lock:
    co.modify_values(1, 2)
```

Comment: Why would the caller of the method need to know about the lock? If it is an implementation detail, make it part of the implementation.

Comment: The right design depends on what the class does. If there's any possibility that you'll ever need to treat two separate API operations as a transaction under the same lock, the lock has to be external. And if the object is a dead simple thing like a `list` where it would make any sense to use it without a lock, the lock has to be either external or optional. But if it's something whose API should promise that each operation is thread-safe, like a `queue.Queue`, the lock should be internal. There's no one-size-fits-all answer; it's part of your object model design.